# assignment from const char pointer to char pointer gives no warnings

Tags: c, pointers, char, constants

Why does the following code raise no Warnings ?

Compiled with -Wall, -Wpedantic, -Wextra, and none of them raise a warning.

```
int main()
{
    const char *p;
    char a[] = "hey";
    p = a;
    (void) p;
    return 0;
}
```

I would expect some kind of warning, such as assignment -Wdiscarded-qualifiers

Comment: Hint: Is the *content* constant, or the pointer itself?

Comment: Which line(s) do you think are problematic?

Comment: What qualifier do you think was discarded and where?

Comment: `a` is initialized with the characters in `"hey"`. `a` is then fully mutable. There is no disregard of `const` in `p = a`. You just can't change `a` through `p`. `(void)p;` is simply a hack to suppress the `-Wunused` warning for `p` (since it was assigned a value but never used).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're assigning *from* a `char *` *to* a `const char *`.  This is safe because you adding the `const` qualifier, not removing it.

If you did this:

```
char *p;
const char a[] = "hey";
p = a;
```

Then you would get a warning about discarding the `const` qualifier.

Answer (score 1):

You are not *discarding* a qualifier. You're *adding* one. This feature is actually pretty important. It's one of those few cases where C actually offers a reasonable option for the programmer to protect himself from himself. For instance, have a look at the prototypes for string manipulation functions in the standard library:

```
char * strcpy ( char * destination, const char * source );
```

This gives us the information that `destination` will be altered, but `source` will not.

From comment below:

> Will it also require that the destination parameter cannot be a const char *

There are  ways around it so it's not *required* per se. We're talking C after all. But if you are planning to use an argument as an output argument it should not be declared as `const`. Here is an example where I'm using a `const` argument as output parameter. It's a function that sets the length of a string to zero:

```
// Note: Bad code. Do not do this at home. Ok, do it at home,
// but do not do it at work.
void removeString(const char * s)
{
    char *p = (char*) s;
    p[0] = 0;
}
```

But in order to do this, you first have to declare a pointer to non-const pointing to s, and then you have to add the cast `(char*)` to get rid of the warning. This is easy to do, but it's quite hard to do by mistake, so it serves as a pretty good protection.

Declaring an argument as a pointer to const gives two things:

1. It tells the programmer using the function that the function will not use the argument as an output argument, unless the author of the function is evil or doesn't know what he is doing.
2. It makes it harder (but not impossible) to change something you should not change by mistake in the function.

Comment: Will it also require that the `destination` parameter cannot be a `const char *`?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Why would you ever declare an object as const if you want to write to it?

Comment: (sorry for my late reaction), I mean if you would try to pass a const object for `destination`, would the compiler complain? It is all about helping the programmer prevent making errors.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Sorry, but I just have to say this. What happened when you tried? ;)

Comment: I haven't tried it, but would find the information valuable to your solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
 assignment from const char pointer to char pointer gives no warnings
```

Your example does something opposite. You assign the pointer to the constant object with the pointer to non constant object. So you do not discard anything hence no worning